# Adding/updating a value+key before an append to array

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file like that I that I am trying to restructure in a certain way. To parse it later on for CSV conversion. The problem is that this JSON contains an extra layer, aka another list, inside of it.

This information I can get of fine but considering there is also a Unique ID value I want to have this too. The thing I just cannot get this done.

The file is structure like this:

```
[
    {
        "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:be_integan_integan:telecommunications",
        "Voorzorgsmaatregelen": [
            {
                "Attributes": {},
                "FileId": "1c610c6d-e87f-4b61-b190-30bda0ec4fdc",
                "FileName": "Voorzorgsmaatregel_be_integan_integan.pdf",
                "FilePackageLocation": "fb83688d-eb41-4536-83cb-12126232addc/Voorzorgsmaatregel_be_integan_integan.pdf"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:waterlink-be:001:V1",
        "Voorzorgsmaatregelen": [
            {
                "Attributes": {},
                "FileId": "1004f541-f797-4d33-98bf-9eee24d591c3",
                "FileName": "20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf",
                "FilePackageLocation": "8ecc6826-d388-449a-832a-18e0b6209b64/20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:waterlink-be:002:V1",
        "Voorzorgsmaatregelen": [
            {
                "Attributes": {},
                "FileId": "1004f541-f797-4d33-98bf-9eee24d591c3",
                "FileName": "20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf",
                "FilePackageLocation": "8ecc6826-d388-449a-832a-18e0b6209b64/20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:crossTheme",
        "Voorzorgsmaatregelen": []
    },
    {
        "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LSOV",
        "Voorzorgsmaatregelen": [
            {
                "Attributes": {},
                "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
                "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
                "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf"
            },
            {
                "Attributes": {},
                "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
                "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
                "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf"
            },
            {
                "Attributes": {},
                "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
                "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
                "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf"
            }
        ]
    },
```

But the code I have here currently, which allows me treat every obj in this JSON file aka utility_netw_json_prevzm_to_save. Take out this UtilitynetworkId as a value for that object, take out de "Voorzorgmaatregelen" part and append it to an list.

```
utility_netw_json_prevzm_to_save = process_all_utility_networks_pre_vzm(json_content_utility_networks_objects)
utility_prevzm_to_save_path = json_to_save(utility_netw_json_prevzm_to_save,folder_path_SJSON_VZM,Utilitynetworks_file_name_pre_VZM)


json_content_vzm_phase_VZM = []



for obj in utility_netw_json_prevzm_to_save:
    key_value = obj.get("utilitynetworkId")
    value_to_be_inserted_before_append = "utilitynetworkId" + ": " +  key_value
    json_object_input = obj.get("Voorzorgsmaatregelen")
    if json_object_input is not []:
        json_content_vzm_phase_VZM.append(json_object_input)
    # json_content_vzm_phase_VZM.update(value_for_first_lis
```

It causes the JSON to look like this, where there also some "empty rows". Because while the ID value does exist there is not always a "Voorzorgsmaatregelen value".

```
[
    [
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "1c610c6d-e87f-4b61-b190-30bda0ec4fdc",
            "FileName": "Voorzorgsmaatregel_be_integan_integan.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "fb83688d-eb41-4536-83cb-12126232addc/Voorzorgsmaatregel_be_integan_integan.pdf"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "1004f541-f797-4d33-98bf-9eee24d591c3",
            "FileName": "20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "8ecc6826-d388-449a-832a-18e0b6209b64/20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "1004f541-f797-4d33-98bf-9eee24d591c3",
            "FileName": "20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "8ecc6826-d388-449a-832a-18e0b6209b64/20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf"
        }
    ],
    [],
    [
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "08d80712-328b-436b-895a-5759d021435c",
            "FileName": "Uitvoering_van_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_installaties_voor_gasdistributie.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Uitvoering_van_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_installaties_voor_gasdistributie.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "08d80712-328b-436b-895a-5759d021435c",
            "FileName": "Uitvoering_van_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_installaties_voor_gasdistributie.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Uitvoering_van_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_installaties_voor_gasdistributie.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "c52bcb4e-30fe-4964-85a6-fd4966f9b6d9",
            "FileName": "begeleidende brief.PDF",
            "FilePackageLocation": "f33f1b51-6f01-493c-8300-9bc6adb4932f/begeleidende brief.PDF"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "59cfaf15-ac40-479e-995c-0e9c24902793",
            "FileName": "EV_KLIP_TLN_Brief_NL.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "8535d359-690d-4f5e-bc4d-a21384125c27/EV_KLIP_TLN_Brief_NL.pdf"
        }
    ]
]
```

What I want to have is this:

```
[
    [
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:be_integan_integan:telecommunications",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "1c610c6d-e87f-4b61-b190-30bda0ec4fdc",
            "FileName": "Voorzorgsmaatregel_be_integan_integan.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "fb83688d-eb41-4536-83cb-12126232addc/Voorzorgsmaatregel_be_integan_integan.pdf"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:waterlink-be:001:V1",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "1004f541-f797-4d33-98bf-9eee24d591c3",
            "FileName": "20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "8ecc6826-d388-449a-832a-18e0b6209b64/20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:waterlink-be:002:V1",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "1004f541-f797-4d33-98bf-9eee24d591c3",
            "FileName": "20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "8ecc6826-d388-449a-832a-18e0b6209b64/20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf"
        }
    ],
    "Empty row this one must be deleted",
    [
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LSOV",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf"
        },
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LSOV",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf"
        },
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LSOV",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:MS",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf"
        },
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:MS",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf"
        },
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:MS",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LD",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "08d80712-328b-436b-895a-5759d021435c",
            "FileName": "Uitvoering_van_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_installaties_voor_gasdistributie.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Uitvoering_van_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_installaties_voor_gasdistributie.pdf"
        },
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LD",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf"
        },
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LD",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf"
        },
        {
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LD",
            "Attributes": {},
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf"
        }
    ],
```

So I need to have two things happen:

1. I need to add the unique ID value to above the "Attributes" for every object
2. The append should not happen if "Voorzorgsmaatregelen "part is [] aka empty

Edit: while the solution provided by Barmar. Put me on the right direction causing me to have code like this.

```
json_content_vzm_phase_1_VZM = []
json_content_vzm_phase_2_VZM = []
    for obj in utility_netw_json_prevzm_to_save:
        json_object_input = obj.get("Voorzorgsmaatregelen")
        if json_object_input:
            key_value = obj.get("utilitynetworkId")
            for obj in json_object_input:
                obj['utilitynetworkId'] = key_value
                del obj['Attributes']
                json_content_vzm_phase_1_VZM.append(json_object_input)
                print(json_content_vzm_phase_1_VZM)
```

It is not the actual solution, I want to have this structure.

```
[
        {
            "FileId": "1c610c6d-e87f-4b61-b190-30bda0ec4fdc",
            "FileName": "Voorzorgsmaatregel_be_integan_integan.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "fb83688d-eb41-4536-83cb-12126232addc/Voorzorgsmaatregel_be_integan_integan.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:be_integan_integan:telecommunications"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "1004f541-f797-4d33-98bf-9eee24d591c3",
            "FileName": "20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "8ecc6826-d388-449a-832a-18e0b6209b64/20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:waterlink-be:001:V1"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "1004f541-f797-4d33-98bf-9eee24d591c3",
            "FileName": "20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "8ecc6826-d388-449a-832a-18e0b6209b64/20210316131654795_20210316133047118.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:waterlink-be:002:V1"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LSOV"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LSOV"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LSOV"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:MS"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:MS"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:MS"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "08d80712-328b-436b-895a-5759d021435c",
            "FileName": "Uitvoering_van_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_installaties_voor_gasdistributie.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Uitvoering_van_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_installaties_voor_gasdistributie.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LD"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LD"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LD"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:LD"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "08d80712-328b-436b-895a-5759d021435c",
            "FileName": "Uitvoering_van_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_installaties_voor_gasdistributie.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Uitvoering_van_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_installaties_voor_gasdistributie.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:MD"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:MD"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:MD"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:MD"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "34f13d98-f438-40b6-9c5d-c49b985f9043",
            "FileName": "Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Begeleidende_brief.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:TCOM"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "6188fc35-8801-4534-abd3-85834bfd3237",
            "FileName": "Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Risicos_en_maatregelen_voor_derden_bij_werken_in_de_nabijheid_van_nutsleidingen.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:TCOM"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "f44a9a01-918e-4ba5-9313-b3ed01e763f4",
            "FileName": "Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "e1f19363-1257-45e9-9714-5948582733e7/Graven_met_zorg.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Ex-Eandis:TCOM"
        },

        {
            "FileId": "c52bcb4e-30fe-4964-85a6-fd4966f9b6d9",
            "FileName": "begeleidende brief.PDF",
            "FilePackageLocation": "f33f1b51-6f01-493c-8300-9bc6adb4932f/begeleidende brief.PDF",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:Proximus-be-Proximus2:001"
        },
        {
            "FileId": "59cfaf15-ac40-479e-995c-0e9c24902793",
            "FileName": "EV_KLIP_TLN_Brief_NL.pdf",
            "FilePackageLocation": "8535d359-690d-4f5e-bc4d-a21384125c27/EV_KLIP_TLN_Brief_NL.pdf",
            "utilitynetworkId": "UtilityNetwork:zone1:UN-001"
        }
]
```

Comment: There's no JSON here. This is just lists of dictionaries. It's irrelevant that you created it from a JSON file -- once you load it, it's just like any other list or dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't create a new dictionary element by concatenating strings. Just assign to the `utilitynetworkId` index of the dictionary.

Don't use `is` or `is not` to compare lists. `is` tests identity, not equality; use `!= []`. Or you can just treat it as a boolean; an empty list is falsey.

```
for obj in utility_netw_json_prevzm_to_save:
    json_object_input = obj.get("Voorzorgsmaatregelen")
    if json_object_input:
        key_value = obj.get("utilitynetworkId")
        for obj in json_object_input:
            obj['utilitynetworkId'] = key_value
            json_content_vzm_phase_VZM.append(obj)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution it kind of solved my problem but I would like that the utilitynetworkId. Gets set above the Arributes and etc. Right now it is below those three keys of "Voorzorgsmaatregelen"

Comment: Thank you once again but I have a different problem now, the structure of the dict is actually inadequate for CSV conversion. This is my mistake because the I thought the desired structure of the JSON would be enough for my CSV conversion function. I will post an updated desired structure.

Comment: The order of dictionary elements is not usually considered significant. Dictionaries remember the order that the keys were added, so you can do this by creating a new dictionary instead of updating the original one.

Comment: I've updated the answer to produce the result you now want. Instead of appending `json_object_input` to the result, you append each `obj`.